# unable to pass a list from viewmodel in a view to a partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basically I have a view model

```
public class VM_MachineCheckSheet
{        
    public List<checksheet> checksheet;
    public List<MvcApplication2.Models.Machine.machine> machine;
}
```

My main View

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.CheckSheet.VM_MachineCheckSheet

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MachineCheckSheet";
}

@Html.RenderPartial("_MachineCheckBoxListPartial", Model.machine);
```

and my Partial View

```
@model IEnumerable&ltMvcApplication2.Models.Machine.machine&gt

<div id = "machine_filter" class = "machine_filter")
<table>
    <tr>
```

I populate the viewmodel in my controller then pass it to the main view and then pass only machine to the partial view which is strongly typed with IEnumerable&ltmachine&gt

this is the error i get

> ```
> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 
> 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)
> 'has some invalid arguments
>
> Line 7:  @Html.RenderPartial("_MachineCheckBoxListPartial", Model.machine);
> ```

I don't know why there is a type mismatch between List of machine in the partial view and the one being passed in from the view model. They are the same thing. Any ideas?

Comment: You are Accepting `IEnumerable`, try changing it to `IList<ltMvcApplication2.Models.Machine.machine>` and properties should be `public IList<checksheet> checksheet;
    public IList<MvcApplication2.Models.Machine.machine> machine;` not List

Comment: i changed machine in my viewmodel to IEnumerable but it still gives the same error unfortunately

Comment: Please check posted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_MachineCheckBoxListPartial", Model.machine);
```

To

```
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_MachineCheckBoxListPartial", Model.machine); }
```

[FOR MORE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5435893/html-renderpartial-giving-me-strange-overload-error)